# Try Catch Not working with Promise and Redux Thunk

Tags: javascript, async-await

Feel free to edit the title as i didn't knew how to properly express .

We are using `React 6.13`,`Babel 7`,`Node 12`

---

Well , i am trying to refactor our thousands lines of code and one of the things i have to do for the duplicate code is create a `try-catch-wrapper` function because we are doing the same for every error .

So below is the wrapper function :

```
const tryToCatch = (func, data ,dispatch) => {
   try {
      func()
      console.log('mmmm')
   } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error)
      console.log(data)
      return handleError(error, data , dispatch)
   }
}
```

And below is how i am trying to call it , i am using `console.log(a)` which prints:

[image]

**BUT IT SEEMS LIKE IT'S NEVER ENTERS `CATCH` because `console.log('Error: ', error)` and
`console.log(data)` are never printed .**

```
export const search = () => async dispatch =>
   tryToCatch(
      async () => {

         //Get Games
         const { data } = await serverApi('GET', '/api/common/games')

         console.log(a) //a is undefined so it will try to catch error

         console.log("hello");

         ..etc code
      },
      dispatch,
      { filtersLoading: false }
   )
```

Comment: The callback function is async, it is not inside the scope of try catch. Try..catch only works synchronously.
Reference: https://javascript.info/try-catch

Comment: Aren't you missing `async` in `tryToCatch` ?

Comment: @KunalGupta All our code is async because our `Client` is waiting for response from `Server` , how i can get around that :) ?

Comment: @MonteCristo Oh my god you are right , i just added `async` on the `try-to-catch` and also `await func()` and it works . Please post an answer :)

Comment: You can make tryToCatch function async and add await before func() in try catch block

Comment: @KunalGupta Exactly what i did :) Thank you , is it a good practice what i did thought :) ?

Comment: @KunalGupta Please feel free to add an answer and i will accept :) Add some info for future users .

Answer (score 1):

The callback function is async, try-catch only works synchronously. You can make tryToCatch an async function and add await before the func() call.

```
const tryToCatch = async (func, data ,dispatch) => {
   try {
      await func()
      console.log('mmmm')
   } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error)
      console.log(data)
      return handleError(error, data , dispatch)
   }
}
```

> Reference: https://javascript.info/try-catch

Comment: I have a problem though , the function seems to be called twice now for some reason i don't understand.

Comment: Where are you using console.log("hello")?

Comment: I have just updated the question and added `console.log("hello"` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
const tryToCatch = async (func, data ,dispatch) => { // Missing `async`
   try {
      await func()
      console.log('mmmm')
   } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error: ', error)
      console.log(data)
      return handleError(error, data , dispatch)
   }
}
```

Comment: I have a problem though , the function seems to be called twice now for some reason i don't understand.